# Standard keyframe animation after soft body/cloth simulation

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, shape-keys, soft-body

I would like to know, how to create simple loc/rot/scale animation or constraint animation after cloth simulation (last frame in simulation cache). When i tried that, it moved only origin of mesh, but not the geometry. I tried to export and import MDD, but animation was wrong after import. I also tried apply as shape key, but than simulation was deleted.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add Vertex group to your cloth object and assign all of the vertices to that group
- Add some Empty object to the scene
- Add hook modifier to the cloth object with the group in Vertex Group slot and Empty as Object.

[image]

- Now you can transform the cloth simulation with that Empty.